# Select2 loading issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Maybe this question is duplicated, but I still dont get why my select2 is not working and i need your help with this.
This is my [site](http://attila-naghi.com/register). If you press ctrl +u you can see that the **jquery** library is loaded, the **select2** script is loaded. I'm getting this error :`$(...).select2 is not a function`

and this is the js script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#country").select2();

    $("#country").change(function(){
        $("#city option").remove();
        value = $(this).val();
        value = value.split("-");
        $.post( "register/get_cities_from_dd", { country_type: value[1]})
            .done(function( data ) {
                obj = JSON.parse(data);
                for(var i in obj) {
                    $('<option>', {
                        text     : obj[i].name,
                        value    : obj[i].id
                    }).prependTo('#city');
                }
        });
        $(".city").show();
    });

});
```

So, the question what Am i missing ?

Comment: I'm not getting that error.  Does this happen when you click the select country dropdown?  If so, it seems to be working fine for me

Comment: please refresh the page and try again, Im getting this error by firebug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have loaded jQuery twice in your page. Remove the first, and then move all script tags to the bottom of the page and then it works.

Comment: I have some css issue , you can see if you refresh the page, but it works. any ideea why is looking weird ? thx  for helping me :)